# Email Attachment as CSV issues

Tags: apex, email, attachment, csv

if I run this code in developer console, I receive the attached csv in an email. However the output of the code is javsscript code instead of the data

[image]

```
    String ReportId = '00O3300000331x3XXX'; 
    ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/'+ReportId+'?csv=1');
    Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();        
    attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
    attachment.setBody(report.getContent());
    attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );

    message.setSubject('Report');

    message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');

    message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'XXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com' } );

    Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, getting a report's content is considered a callout.  If you schedule this class, it fails and sends this bad file.

Create another method with @future(callout=true) and call it from the scheduled class.  It should work then.

Also, unless you have checking logic elsewhere, this email will likely be sent even when the report has no rows.

Source: had this same issue when emailing an excel version of a report via apex.

Edit: here's a thread and sample code.
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008n0zIAA

```
global class Exporter implements System.Schedulable {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        DoExport();
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void DoExport() {
        ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/00O500000000000?csv=1');
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        attachment.setFileName('report.csv');
        attachment.setBody(Blob.valueof(report.getContent().toString()));
        attachment.setContentType('text/csv');
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        message.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
        message.setSubject('Report');
        message.setPlainTextBody('The report is attached.');
        message.setToAddresses( new String[] { 'asdf@asdf.com' } );
        Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { message } );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  I create a new class and copied/pasted the exact code (changed reportID, and seTToAddress).  I scheduled the report. Got an email with attachment. However the attached csv is still the same  as shown in the screenshot in my original question. I wonder is it about some setting in my outlook. Can you please execute the sample code and check if you are seeing the data in attached csv.?

Comment: Got it!!!! I read through all the discussions in the reference you provided. I replaced the  ApexPages.PageReference... with following and i get the data in the attached csv. 

ApexPages.PageReference report = new ApexPages.PageReference('/REPORT_ID?csv=1&exp=1&enc=UTF-8&isdtp=p1'); // REPORT_ID = 'id of the report'

Basically, this line works with lightning. Thanks JIM!!!!!!